# Chang of loop to generate scatter plots in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, matplotlib

I have loop like below:

```
for feature1 in numeric_features:
    for feature2 in [var for var in numeric_features if var != feature1]:
        scatter_plot(f"{zmienna1}", f"{zmienna2}", "Overweight")
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.show()
```

This loop generate scatter plots, using function created by me, for combination feature1 x feature 2, nevetheless how can I change this loop so as to do not generate 2 time the same plots but with other combination of features.

For example I have plot 1 Height vs Age :
[image]

ANd I have plot 2 Age vs Height:

[image]

And I need to change this loop so as to generate only one scatter plot for combination feature1 vs feature2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use itertools:

```
import itertools

for feature1,feature2 in itertools.combinations(numeric_features,2):
    scatter_plot(f"{zmienna1}", f"{zmienna2}", "Overweight")
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```